# Starting a vimeo video at a specific start time with fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox, fancybox-2, vimeo

I am able to start a vimeo video at a specific start point by adding #t=1m15s to the video url. For example:
    `https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/119293996#t=1m15s`

But when I use fancybox media helper it seems to remove the #t=1m15s from the url and wont start from the desired time.

Anyone know a way i can start the video at the desired start time using fancybox?

**Update:**

Below is the code I am using:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/jquery.fancybox.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fancybox/2.1.5/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".fancybox").fancybox();
            $('.fancybox-media').fancybox({
                openEffect  : 'none',
                closeEffect : 'none',
                helpers : {
                    media : {}
                }
            });
        });
    </script>

<a href="https://vimeo.com/channels/staffpicks/119293996#t=1m15s" class="fancybox-media">test</a>
```

Here is a jsfidlle: http://jsfiddle.net/8z3ueL23/

Comment: @Devpaq provide JSFiddle

Comment: @Moogs, a jsFiddle would be great, **however**, a jsFiddle does **not** negate the need for including the code within a fully self-contained OP.

Comment: Have you tried URL encoding the `#` into `%23`?

Comment: I updated the question with my code and a jsfiddle (sorry I'm new to this)

Comment: Encoding does not seem to help. It looks like fancybox rewrites the iframe url and removes it

Answer (score 1):

Looking [at this line in jquery.fancybox-media.js](https://github.com/fancyapps/fancyBox/blob/master/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js#L106), the regular expression is not handling the hash. The hash needs to be stripped out and appended to the player url.

I recommend filing a bug.

Comment: Thanks! I will file a bug and see if they correct it.

Answer (score 1):

While you can file a bug, you can always pass additional parameters to vimeo with this format

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    $(".fancybox-media").fancybox({
        helpers : {
            media : true
        },
        vimeo : {
            "t" : "1m15s"
        }
    });
}); // ready
```

The issue is that parameters are appended to the URI using the `&` sign, however vimeo will also support the `&#t=1m15s` format :
[player.vimeo.com/video/{video_id}?autoplay=1&#t=1m15s](http://player.vimeo.com/video/119293996?autoplay=1&hd=1&show_title=1&show_byline=1&show_portrait=0&fullscreen=1&#t=1m15s)

For that reason you could try to pass the *hash* like :

```
vimeo : {
    "#t" : "1m15s"
}
```

The problem is that fancybox media helper will encode the *hash* and produce something like :

```
player.vimeo.com/video/{video_id}?autoplay=1&%23t=1m15s
```

... which is not supported.

As a(n) (ugly) workaround, you could add the (unencoded) *hash* `time` parameter within the `afterLoad` callback like

```
afterLoad : function () {
    var _src = $(".fancybox-iframe").attr("src") + "&#t=1m15s";
    $(".fancybox-iframe").attr("src", _src);
}
```

**[image: JSFIDDLE]**

**Notice** we still need to load the media helpers js file